# Is volatile useful at all in a singlethreaded application in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, single-threaded

As in the title - is there any case in which volatile is useful in the context of single-thread programming in Java? I know it's used to make sure the value of the variable is always actually checked in memory so is there any case in which that value may change (in a singlethreaded application) in a way that the app/compiler won't notice?

Comment: Not in any case that I can think about.

Comment: I am not sure about authenticity of [this website](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile_when.shtml) but it lists very clearly the situations when `volatile` has no use and your case is one of those items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, at least not for your own defined variables in a single-threaded application.

The `volatile` keyword guarantees happens-before relationships with multiple reads of that variable, which only makes sense when multiple threads access it.

Additional insights [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html).

Comment: `volatile` guarantees visibility and ordering, not atomicity.

Comment: @AndyTurner, `volatile` variables ensure atomic reads and writes apart from visibility... See the link in the answer...

Answer (score 1):

It is not useful from the point of view described in the question, but it can affect code execution:

Happens-before semantics make restrictions for program instruction reordering. Usually if you have

```
private int a;
private int b;
private boolean ready;

void calc(int x, int z) {
   a = x + 5;
   b = z - 3;
   ready = true;
}
```

JIT compiler is allowed to execute method instructions in any order (for performance reasons).

But if you add volatile keyword: `private volatile boolean ready`, then its guaranteed that first two operations would be executed before `true` will be assigned to `ready` variable. This is still pretty useless, but technically there is a difference.

Comment: Re _technically there is a difference_, There may be a difference under the hood, but if adding `volatile` to your example makes a difference in the outcome of a single threaded program, then the Java/JVM implementation is defective.

Comment: @jameslarge i didn't say that. example shows difference for JIT instruction reordering.